# How to fire an event on a link click for Isotope.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to add an function to an a click event to my code. This is to use Isotope.js, a pretty cool jQuery tool, by the way.

So the code below works as follows: Clicking on the data-filter link in the `<ul>` fires isotope. That populates the page with the various `<li>` that match the data-filter parameter. All good.

But then I have additional code that modifies the size of one `<li>` so I need isotope to fire the following  on the click of any `<li>` - Isotope is a dynamic page layout tool that uses masonry.

```
.isotope( 'reLayout', callback )
```

Which resets layout properties and lays-out every item element.
See - [isotope.js relayout](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html#relayout)

I think I just need another piece of code for the script that triggers the relayout function when an `<li>` is clicked.

This is what I have...

```
<ul><a class="black" href="#" data-filter=".'.$folder.'">'.$folder.'</a> </ul>';

<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.rtrim($name,'.mp3').'</a></li>;

<script>
  $('#filters a').click(function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('#container').isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});

$('#container').isotope({
  masonry : {
    columnWidth : 1
  }

 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
      // change size of clicked element
      $container.delegate( '.element', 'click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('large');
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
      });
```

This is the code http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/relayout.html page uses when they do exactly what you are trying to do. This same approach should work for you to.

So $container would be your $("#container") and .element would be the same as the elements in your container. This adds or removes a class "large" which the class "large" has css which gives that element a larger size. Then as you noted the isotope gets called with "relayout".

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast... believe me, I've really tried with the documentation on the site. The part I don't get is that he is toggling the size with his code. My <li> links trigger a whole bunch of code (soundmanager2) that does the resizing. So I just want to very simply say: trigger the relayout when the user clicks on an <li>. Possible?

Comment: Hi,Thanks - that did work. I had to just remove the line about toggling the class.